# How do I intercept downloads from a WKWebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, wkwebview, download

I am making a Cocoa app that involves users selecting pictures from online for use within the app. I am also looking to collect contextual metadata from those downloads, such as the host the image came from, the website the user was visiting, the exact MIME type in the response headers, etc.

Basically I want to curate my user across the internet, downloading images and metadata into that user's account as I go. Until today I thought this would be impossible.

But just recently I was toying with a WKWebView and I tried right clicking on an image. I saw this...

[image]

Is there any way I could connect to that *Download Image* button, and get notifications when its clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out how to make "Download Linked File" work and its a doozy that will not fit in a SO answer: https://github.com/kfix/MacPin/commit/9e5f925819f7f54ef29baff1e90783b820e683a3

However implementing those private delegate functions doesn't seem to allow "Download Image" to signal my WkWebView app in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept those non-working "Download Image" and "Download Linked File" menu items by subclassing the WKWebView class and implementing the `willOpenMenu` method like this:

```
class MyWebView: WKWebView {

    override func willOpenMenu(_ menu: NSMenu, with event: NSEvent) {
        for menuItem in menu.items {
            if  menuItem.identifier == "WKMenuItemIdentifierDownloadImage" ||
                menuItem.identifier == "WKMenuItemIdentifierDownloadLinkedFile" {
                menuItem.action = #selector(menuClick(sender:))
                menuItem.target = self
            }
        }
    }

    func menuClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let menuItem = sender as? NSMenuItem {
            Swift.print("Menu \(menuItem.title) clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of this you can also simply hide the menu items with `menuItem.isHidden = true`

Detecting the chosen menu item is one thing, but knowing *what* the user actually clicked in the WKWebView control is the next challenge :)